# How can you point an HTML object's data attribute to an in-line SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

My site reuses the same 3 JS-animated clickable SVGs on each of a page's 63 post elements, and they seem to take forever to load/seriously hinder page performance. (Slow performance happens while using 3*63 separate HTML objects to pull in the same 3 external SVGs).

I'm trying to reduce my site's load time by only loading them once (either as [an object w/ data attribute pointed to an external SVG file](https://codepen.io/moodyeffects/pen/3cee7ebe81a8d382f9c58061c7a3f804?editors=1100), or by loading them in the HTML [as an in-line SVG](https://codepen.io/moodyeffects/pen/8dba487409c867b4d6935a7f5d985653)), and then referencing their ID tag in an another object's data attribute, but this doesn't seem to work.

I made two example CodePens linked above to illustrate the issue, and copied the code from the external version below.

The end goal is just to reduce code (vs in-lining all 63*3 SVGs), and to improve performance/reduce loading times.

If I'm going about this the wrong way, please show me a better way to do this.

```
<object id="likeButton" type="image/svg+xml" data="https://www.charliemoody.com/s/likeButton.svg">
</object>

<object class="likeButtonClones" type="image/svg+xml" data="#likeButton">
</object>
```

Comment: No but you could convert the inline SVG files to data URLs and use them that way.

Comment: svgs are usually pretty lightweight. you can try and slim them down more by using some build tools if you're already using them, or you can try running it through this online tool https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/
i'd start looking other places for performance hits before looking at svgs, but if you're sure that's the problem Robert's right you could use data urls and css background-images to get them loaded once

Comment: @RobertLongson Ah, dang. Wouldn't the interactive (i.e. clickable) JS SVG animations not work when using data URLs, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @JohnHooper The SVGs I'm using (including the one in the CodePens) were all run through SVGOMG after animating and exporting them using SVGator. [Here's a link to the page in question](https://codepen.io/moodyeffects/pen/89e47d75c5337fd5c40d6e7a7d363fbc). You're probably right that it's other content causing the performance hits, but the animated SVG icons seem to be effected most.

Comment: @CharlieMoody it's how you use the data url that counts, so yes you are mistaken.

Comment: @RobertLongson I think I get it. [Is this](https://codepen.io/moodyeffects/pen/61b241998d966542112e33d57782d051?editors=1000) what you mean? Also, are there any performance-related benefits to using the data URL as opposed to the inline SVG? Looks to be a few hundred characters longer than the regular inline. Thanks for the help!